# ActiveMQ in Eclipse to listen to remote broker

Tags: eclipse, maven, activemq-classic

My goal is to listen to a broker on a port on a specific IP address with a given topic to receive JMS messages from there with ActiveMQ in Eclipse IDE.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
    
    Connection Connection = null;
    try {
        // Producer
        ConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://1.2.3.4:5678");
        
        Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        Connection.start();
        Session session = Connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
        Topic topic = session.createTopic("MyTopic");
        
        // Consumer1 subscribes to customerTopic
        MessageConsumer consumer1 = session.createConsumer(topic);
        consumer1.setMessageListener(new MessageConsumeListener("MyTopic"));
               
        System.out.print("connected");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        /* session.close(); */
    } finally {
        if (Connection != null) {
            Connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://1.2.3.4.5678 Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:360)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245)
    at My.Project.subscribelistener.main(subscribelistener.java:29)
```

And also this:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:501)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:464)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:168)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:340)
    ... 3 more
```

I can also ping the IP address and with `telnet` I can connect to the port.

How can I connect to a remote broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram : Thanks for the quick answer. I updated the stack-trace of the Exception.

Comment: I'm not sure anything can be done from an ActiveMQ perspective. The client is using the `Socket` implementation from the JVM to make the connection but it's not working. The connection is being refused which is almost certainly an environmental issue. What happens if you run your client outside Eclipse or directly on the machine hosting ActiveMQ?

Comment: Sorry, there was just bad communication. ActiveMQ was not the right process to use since the broker didn`t have anything to do with ActiveMQ.